# Как установить расстояние между буквами в Pango?

Tags: c++, c, gui, gtk

Я делаю свою программу на GTK, решил добавить к GtkLabel немного разнообразия. Нашёл функцию `gtk_label_set_attributes`, накидал такой код:

```c
label_attr = pango_attr_list_new();

label_size = pango_attr_size_new(12);
label_font = pango_attr_family_new("Source Code Pro");
label_stretch = pango_attr_stretch_new(PANGO_STRETCH_NORMAL);
label_font_variant = pango_attr_variant_new(PANGO_VARIANT_NORMAL);
label_font_weight = pango_attr_weight_new(PANGO_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
label_letter_spacing = pango_attr_letter_spacing_new(5);
label_rise = pango_attr_rise_new(5);

pango_attr_list_insert(label_attr, label_size);
pango_attr_list_insert(label_attr, label_font);
pango_attr_list_insert(label_attr, label_stretch);
pango_attr_list_insert(label_attr, label_font_variant);
pango_attr_list_insert(label_attr, label_font_weight);
pango_attr_list_insert(label_attr, label_letter_spacing);
pango_attr_list_insert(label_attr, label_rise);

gtk_label_set_attributes(GTK_LABEL(text_label), label_attr);
```

Но при выводе самого текста, буквы накладываются одна на другую. Это при том, что я установил аттрибут `letter_spacing`. Как сделать так, чтобы буквы разделялись?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что расстояние между графемами в Pango измеряется не в пикселях, а единицах Pango. Одна единица Pango численно равна 1024. Для шрифта `Source Code Pro` оптимальным будет расстояние в 12 единиц Pango. Таким образом нужно изменить строку:

```c
label_letter_spacing = pango_attr_letter_spacing_new(5);
```

на

```c
label_letter_spacing = pango_attr_letter_spacing_new(1024 * 12);
```

Так же стоит добавить атрибут запасного шрифта:

```c
label_fallback = pango_attr_fallback_new(TRUE);
...
pango_attr_list_insert(label_attr, label_fallback);
```